# Jquery not working in github pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure why jquery isnt working. I can't get my slide show to move. I know it's probably something wrong with my code, just can't figure out what. I don't know if Jquery even is supposed to work on github
but here's some of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>portfolio</title>
<style>


#inside{
 width: 100%;
 height: 820px;
 border:0px solid green ;
background-color: #F1F1F1;
 margin-top: -150px;

}
#inside2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    border: 0px solid black;
    margin-top: 0PX;
margin-left: -20px;
}


#person{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-left: 120px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    position:relative;
}
#arnd2{
transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-top: 100px;
position:relative;
    width: 1300px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 0px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#square1{
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
position:absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border:  3px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
#square2{
margin-left: 370px;
    margin-top:100px;
position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
#square3{
    margin-left: 820px;
    margin-top:100px;
position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
}

.arnd{

    margin-left: 0px;
    background-size: 100%,700px;
    height: 700px;
margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0px solid #c9a9b2;

}

img{

    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -200px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
img #bottom2{
position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
margin-top: 470px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
#fash{

    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: 0px;

}




#diamond1{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    border:0px solid black;
    margin-left: -200PX;
    margin-top: 230PX;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 1px;


}

#diamond2{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 550px;
    border:0px solid pink;
    margin-left: 450PX;
    margin-top:-1265px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 1px;
}

#diamond3{
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    border:0px solid black;
    margin-left: 1000PX;
    margin-top:-600PX;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 1px;

}


hover:#diamond1,#diamond2,#diamond3{
border-radius: 100%;


}

#logo{

    margin-top:20px; 
    width: 250px;
height: 250px;

margin-left: 620px;
}


h1{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid white;
position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 130px;
    font-family:goldoni;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
margin-top: -350px;
margin-left: -730px;
color: white;
z-index: 1px;
width: 900px;
padding: 30px;

}
#back{

position:absolute;
    font-size: 70px;
    width: 500px;
padding: 40px;
background-color: black;
border: 1px solid black;
opacity: 0.7;
    margin-top:-10px;
margin-left: -150px;    
}
#hide2{
        display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid white;

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 130px;
    font-family:goldoni;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
margin-top: -350px;
margin-left: 230px;
color: white;
z-index: 1px;
width: 900px;
padding: 30px;
display: none;
}
#arrow{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: 1200px;
}
#arrow2{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}


#hide{
        display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid white;

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family:goldoni;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
margin-top: -350px;
margin-left: 430px;
color: white;
z-index: 1px;
width: 870px;
padding: 40px;
display: none;

}

p{
        font-family: carolina hills personal use;
margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
position: absolute;
color: BLACK;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
margin-top: 200px;
}
#line{
    margin-top: 230px;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
margin-left: 225px;
    width: 1000PX;

}
#icon{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1300px;
    margin-top:50px;


}






</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"> </script>

    <script >

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#arrow2").mouseover(function(){

        $("#diamond1,#diamond2,#diamond3").animate({"left":"600px"},1000,function(){


$("h1").hide();
$("#hide2").show();
$("#hide").hide();

});


});

$("#diamond2").mouseover(function(){
        $("#diamond1,#diamond2,#diamond3").animate({"left":"0px"},1000,function(){;
$("h1").show();
$("#hide").hide();
$("#hide2").hide();
});
    });
$("#arrow").mouseover(function(){
        $("#diamond1,#diamond2,#diamond3").animate({"left":"-400px"},1000,function(){
$("h1").hide();
$("#hide2").hide();
$("#hide").show();


});
});
});

    </script>
```

Comment: where are your diamond elements?

Comment: Please remove codes which are unwanted so as to ease the debugging

Comment: You missing a `<body>` for starters.

Comment: `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"` ... perhaps the page is using https ... check your *browsers* **developer** tools console for hints .... and load external resources like `src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"` where possible

Comment: thanks taking the https: out of the jquery src code worked!!!!

Comment: With help from @JaromandaX comment, I needed to change to `src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"` to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem it´s the github pages resource it´s working on HTTPS connection and the JQuery CDN it´s on a HTTP connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#diamond2").mouseover(function(){
        $("#diamond1,#diamond2,#diamond3").animate({"left":"0px"},1000,function(){;
$("h1").show();
```

Remove the semicolon after function(){ ; <-- This might be breaking things for you.

Comment: can you give me the current page address and I will take a quick look.

Comment: I tried with the code you provided and threw out everything that I didnt have to do with the JS and it worked ok. To see if Jquery is working on your page or not try this code  if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
   }